# How can I print every line in a text file without an emtpy line in between? Python

Tags: python-3.x

Code:

```
opener = open("gymclub.txt", "r")
for line in opener:
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
Alex,45,7

Kier,67,18

Ben,66,19

Jack,75,29

Harry,25,1

Zeki,8,0

Dagnis,10,2

Ryan,33,15

Tobilola,30,9

Chris,74,24

Sebastian,73,28
```

I need it to print these lines but without the empty lines in between. I've had this problem before and I've solved it but I can't remember what the solution was. I can't find any solutions online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
print(line, end ="")
```

---

Or you can use this:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if this helped :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll accept this answer in 6 minutes when it lets me.

Comment: Sure thing! I am glad I was able to help.